# JAVA - Calling a method Inside a jframe from another class

Tags: java, class, package, jframe

I have a Jframe with a method that clear text of a text area :

```
//in  bgui.java(jframe)
public void clear_log(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ui, "foo");
    terminal.setText("");
}
```

and also i have method in another package in a class that call `clear_log` method:

```
//in Bcommsnd.java
public int parse_command(String cmd){
     Bgui ui = new Bgui();
     ui.clear_log();
}
```

the message shown but `setText()` command not working.
any sugestion please

Comment: have you made sure that the TextArea is visible at all? Have you called setText() before or initialized it with a default text?

Comment: Text area is visible at all and setText called with a defualt text.

Comment: Are you updating the components? Maybe you are blocking the thread from updating the components. Take a look at `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` for some help.

Comment: Wait - in parse_command, you're creating a new instance of Bgui - where are you configuring the terminal instance variable?

Comment: `//in Bcommand.java
public int parse_command(String cmd , Bgui ui){
     ui.clear_log();
}`